How to connect Django 5.0.3 to SQL Server database 2024
I have been trying to connect Django with SQL server but there are errors occurring continuously no matter what I try.
For example
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'xxxxx',
        'USER': 'xxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        'HOST': 'xxxxx',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}

I get this error:
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py", line 180, in as_sql
    raise FullResultSet
django.core.exceptions.FullResultSet

When I change Engine to "mssql" I get this error:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mssql' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

I have also tried the solution that is provided here
But it didn't work also that solution is from 2017 and 2022.
It's 2024. If there is anyone who can help, please reach out.

And have you imported the correct backend as the second error tells you?

@DaleK I believe I have. Upon doing pip freeze I see this
mssql==1.0.1
mssql-django==1.5

have you tried using pip install django-mssql-backend link

@Allprod PS C:\Users\Admin\dream> pip install django-mssql-backend
Requirement already satisfied: django-mssql-backend in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyodbc>=3.0 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from django-mssql-backend) (5.1.0)
Resulting in this Error: django.core.exceptions.FullResultSet

You have to install mssql-django, sql_server.pyodbc is quite old and unmaintained you shouldn't be using it.

Adding a date doesn't really differentiate your question from previous ones. You have to point out how it doesn't answer your question. For example: "I tried installing and using mssql-django as per XYZ answer but got the following error ..." Unless you have some specific error though the mssql-django package as described in some of the answers on the linked question should work for the version of Django you talk about so the duplicate closure is valid.

@HiraSadiq can we get a full Traceback?

"it didn't work" isn't a helpful statement; explain why it didn't work. As for that the solution is from 2022, that doesn't make it not relevant in 2024.
